# Action Bar Sherlock - Odd menu behaviour when hardware menu button is present

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am seeing some strange behaviour from ABS whenever a hardware menu is present on a device.  Menu items which aught to be on the actionbar do not appear. Pressing the menu button does open the overflow and the items which you would expect to be there do appear.

The app in question consists of a main SherlockFragmentActivity, which swaps out various SherlockFragments. Some of the fragments contain FragmentStatePagers which host many other SherlockFragments. It's the fragments that appear in the pagers that exhibit the problem.

I create menus in the usual manner

#### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

#### Fragment1.java

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_one, menu);
}
```

Interestingly, whenever I navigate away from a fragment with the back key I see the missing menu items for half a second. Almost as though they are on the previous fragment.

This problem seems pretty uniform across all android versions, there just needs to be a hardware menu key present.

Any help appreciated.

-- Edit -- 
Looks like pressing the actual menu key and opening the overflow menu then closing it, causes the missing items to appear. So strange.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the problem, I can't seem to be able to reproduce it. A screenshot or two would have been helpful.

Comment: If a hardware menu-key is available, then the overflown menus are hidden from ActionBar and shown only by pressing the menu-key. Its the default behavior.

Comment: As stated, the overflown items aren't the problem. The problem is the items that should be on the action bar.

Comment: Are you specifying the `showAsAction` attribute in your menu XML?

Comment: Yes. I have tried all the various values that go with that, nothing fixes it. If I show the fragment on it's own (not in a view pager) then I see the missing menu items. To be clear the overflow items always so up.